# How do I get elevateZoom to position the lens at mouse cursor center?

Tags: javascript, css, position

How do I get elevateZoom (http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom) to position the lens at mouse-cursor center? The problem is that when I hover the main image the lens appears offset from my cursor. ElevateZoom's inserts the following two divs into the DOM positioned left: 86px and top: 178px. But I want the divs zoomContainer and zoomLens positioned at left: 0 top: 0.

```
<div class="zoomContainer" style="position: absolute; left: 86px; top: 178px; height: 574px; width: 453px;">
    <div class="zoomLens" style="background-position: 0px 0px; float: right; overflow: hidden; z-index: 999; opacity: 0.4; width: 201.333px; height: 200.875px; background-color: white; cursor: default; border: 1px solid black; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;"> 
</div>
```

Below is my code

**HTML**

```
<div id="images">
    <div class="image current">
        <span>
            <img id="zoom_01" src="img/product1_small.jpg" data-zoom-image="img/product1.jpg">
            <div class="zoomContainer" style="position: absolute; left: 86px; top: 178px; height: 574px; width: 453px;">
                <div class="zoomLens" style="background-position: 0px 0px; float: right; overflow: hidden; z-index: 999; opacity: 0.4; width: 201.333px; height: 200.875px; background-color: white; cursor: default; border: 1px solid black; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="zoomBox"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({
    zoomWindowWidth: 400,
    zoomWindowHeight: 400,
    zoomType: 'window',
    zoomWindowPosition: 'zoomBox'
});
```

**CSS**

```
#zoomBox{
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px; height: 400px;
    right: -100%;
    border: 5px solid #000;
}
.image{
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}
.image.current{
    left: 0;
}
.image span{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand from the above what is going wrong and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @eleven11 currently elevateZoom calculates the ".zoomContainer" class top and left position relative to the browser window. But since the ".image" class is position: absolute, the ".zoomContainer" div gets positioned relative to the ".image" class, and thus offset by how far my image element is from the browser window instead of at left: 0 top: 0 relative to the ".image" class. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Looks like you got this sorted out now.
https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/commit/86e9e85087ab8f1f0ac1b9f2a2a0aeb0b141a59c

Good Effort